# L'adjectif « malaisant » : France ou Québec, registre, etc. ?

Tags: vocabulaire, origine-ou-raison, lexique, registre

L'adjectif [*malaisant*](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?T1=malaisant&T3.x=0&T3.y=0&id=5264) pour « ce qui provoque ou cause un malaise » est inconnu des dictionnaires Larousse, TLFi et DHLF, alors que Hachette le note familier et que le [Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/malaisant) le dit du Québec. Personnellement je le croyais plutôt familier, ou régional, et j'entretenais même l'idée que ça pouvait provenir du [français](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fran%C3%A7ais_acadien) des provinces atlantiques, que j'associe généralement à un français plus ancien que le mien (à tort ou à raison) ; en plus je le sens comme un participe présent basé sur un verbe que je ne connais pas. Sauf qu'ensuite on le retrouve en France :

> L’œil se perd, ne sait pas trop où regarder : le bassin verdâtre où
>   flotte une statue humanoïde ? La maquette d’un bâtiment ? La vidéo
>   d’une émission de télé-crochet thaïlandais où une jeune femme frotte
>   son corps enduit de peinture sur une toile blanche, comme une
>   performance d’Yves Klein ? Les murs couverts d’explosions multicolores
>   ? Il n’y a là aucun effet **malaisant**, plutôt une gêne, une question
>   qui naît : qu’est ce que c’est que ce bazar ?
>
> [ [Korakrit Arunanondchai, esprit de ciel](http://next.liberation.fr/culture/2015/07/21/korakrit-arunanondchai-esprit-de-ciel_1351533), ds. *Libération*,
>   article de Clément Ghys, 21 juillet 2015 à 20:46, je souligne ; exemple mentionné à la BDL. ]

Qui plus est, ce serait apparu dans la presse en France en 1995 et au Québec en 2005 : l'emploi en France précéderait donc celui au Québec, et dans tous les cas ce serait un emploi récent (BDL). On reste personnellement surpris.

---

- S'agit-il de deux emplois distincts au Québec et en France, de quel registre ça relève, est-ce la même chose à l'oral ; a-t-on d'autres précisions ?
- Je fais mienne l'essentiel de la question à l'[article](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?T1=malaisant&T3.x=0&T3.y=0&id=5264) de la BDL : d'où viendrait spontanément le cas échéant cet adjectif et pourquoi le besoin d'avoir ce
  terme qui évite une périphrase (*qui rend/met...*) se
  manifesterait-il de manière si contemporaine (<25 ans) alors que le verbe
  [malaiser](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/dmf/malaiser?idf=complXpcYXcbjjc;str=0) du [Berry](http://www.littre.org/definition/malais%C3%A9) est lui éteint depuis fort longtemps et
  que [malaisé](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/malais%C3%A9) est souvent vieilli ?

Comment: Je ne crois pas que Stackexchange soit le bon endroit pour demander à des non-spécialiste de réaliser une étude lexicologique complète pour toi.

Comment: @Circeus Je me souviens que mes propos dans un commentaire avaient pu être blessants et je m'en excuse. J'étais excédé par la gratuité du vote négatif sur les questions alors qu'elles sont déjà moins récompensées que les réponses. Mais c'est ainsi que les site fonctionne et c'est la vie. Merci.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Je ne sais pas s’il y a un lien direct entre le très disparu verbe *malaiser* et l’adjectif *malaisant*, mais j’aurais tendence à penser que son action fut plutôt indirecte. Je verrais que la notion de *« ressentir un malaise »* ait progressivement pavé le chemin à celle de *« délibérement faire ressentir un malaise »,* de laquelle aurait éventuellement émergé ce mot, *malaisant*, concentrant en trois syllabes cette notion, qui put dès lors s’incorporer facilement dans une phrase sans l’allourdir. Pourquoi ce mot a-t-il pris cette forme en particulier? Là peut-être pourrait se cacher le verbe *malaiser*.

---

**Quelques périphrases récemment cristallisées**

Si l’on explore un instant quelques mots d’apparition relativement récente, ou devenus populaires il y a peu, on pourra trouver de semblables contractions de périphrases, ayant différents niveaux de succès :

- **anxiogène** *(qui génère l’angoisse)* est probablement compris par la plupart des gens, mais son utilisation demeure limitée.
- **capilotracté** *(qui est tiré par les cheveux)* connaît un succès d’estime, mais semble utilisé beaucoup plus par plaisanterie et boutade que sérieusement *(le terme étant lui-même, jusqu’à preuve du contraire, capilotracté, on pourra supposer que cette autoréférence n’est pas pour rien dans sa popularité et sa valeur le plus souvent comique).*
- **chronophage** *(qui nécessite beaucoup de temps)* est très peu utilisé en général, mais semble connaître une existence paisible dans les milieux intellectuels, charmés sans doute par les racines grecques appliquées de manière si inattendue. L’indifférence que montrent les dictionnaires usuels à son égard ne change apparemment rien à son statut ou à son utilisation.
- **jouissif** *(qui provoque [une version modeste de] la jouissance)*, dont les premières attestations datent des années 1940, est aujourd’hui très bien accepté.

---

**Des participes de verbes peu usités**

Le français possède un certain nombre d’adjectifs tirés de participes présents ou passés, dont le verbe-source est plus rare, parfois disparu. Parfois, le sens de l’adjectif s’est plus ou moins dissocié du verbe qui a présidé à sa création, au point qu’un parallèle entre les deux peut s’avérer délicat à tracer, et que les divergences égalent et surpassent à l’occasion les convergences. Dans les cas cités ci-dessous pour lesquels le verbe n’existe plus ou pratiquement plus dans la langue contemporaine, une utilisation ou re-création du verbe par plaisanterie aurait de fortes chances d’être comprise, si pas forcément approuvée.

- **arrogant** Si cet adjectif est bien issu d’un participe présent latin, le verbe *arroger*, de même racine, n’a plus la même prononciation du G, et leurs sens respectifs sont aussi suffisamment distincts pour qu’il soit laborieux de jeter des ponts entre les deux.
- **catastrophé** Atterré. Cet adjectif vient du participe passé d’un verbe qui est justement le plus souvent utilisé au participe passé. L’utilisation de l’adjectif semble en essort depuis quelques années et a aussi connut une autre période de popularité au XIXe siècle, à en croire [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=catastroph%C3%A9%2Ccatastropher&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccatastroph%C3%A9%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccatastropher%3B%2Cc0). Le verbe, quant à lui, ne semble pas profiter de ces vagues et son usage varie beaucoup moins.
- **exorbitant** Du verbe latin *exorbitare (s’écarter de),* incluant *orbita (voie tracée).* Excessif, exagéré. Le verbe *exorbiter* est rarement utilisé, mais un participe passé virtuel a éventuellement émergé vers la fin du XIXe siècle pour devenir l’adjectif **exorbité**, pour lequel *orbite* désigne l’orbite des yeux, ce qui nous donne une image frappante dont la bande dessinée aura par la suite fait grand usage.
- **exubérant** Qui est très abondant; en parlant d’une personne, qui est très expansif dans ses manières. Tiré du participe présent du verbe *exuberare*, on retrouve en français, rarement, parfois par volonté délibérée de le mettre à la mode, le verbe *exubérer*.

  > *« Ça la changeait des soupers de théâtre. Amenée par un critique d’alors, non sans crédit, on avait dû lui faire la leçon, d’avoir à ne pas trop exubérer...*
  >   *(Exubérer ? J’arrête, je compulse Larousse. Parfaitement : exubérer, — peu usité. Remettons-le en activité.) » – in Mercure de France, 1936*
- **fendant** Arrogant, prétentieux. Ce québécisme est peut-être un euphémisme qui voile délicatement en l’effaçant le fait que quelqu’un de fendant est quelqu’un qui *fend le cul (comprendre, qui fait chier).* La disparition du complément laisse finalement à l’adjectif assez peu de liens avec un bûcheron qui fend son bois, un faucon qui fend les airs ou un navire qui fend les flots. Même la fente en quatre de cheveux *(la tétracapilectomie, comme disait le regretté Umberto Eco)* est plus près de l’usage habituel du verbe *fendre*.
- **frappant** Un détail frappant ne frappe que l’imagination, un argument frappant a un peu plus de la vigueur du verbe *frapper*, mais demeure au final tout immatériel. Il y a donc une certaine dissociation entre le verbe et l’adjectif.
- **gluant** L’adjectivation de ce participe présent du verbe *gluer* n’a pas suivi son verbe-mère lorsque celui-ci est devenu *engluer*.
- **haletant** est beaucoup utilisé de nos jours pour décrire des polars, des films d’action ou des jeux vidéo. Le verbe *haleter* dont il vient est aussi utilisé, mais son utilisation est pratiquement toujours liée à l’essoufflement véritable plutôt qu’à une perte de souffle virtuelle provoquée par des situations périlleuses vécues par procuration.
- **parlant** Il est curieux de penser que des statistiques parlantes sont si claires qu’elles se passent très bien de tout commentaire. En le réduisant au silence, on s’éloigne assez du verbe dont il est issu.
- **récalcitrant** Rétif. Le verbe *récalcitrer* dont il est tiré est très rare aujourd’hui; il date des débuts du français et on trouve son équivalent en latin.
- **redondant** Qui se répète ou s’étend trop longtemps. Le verbe *redonder (qui foisonne)* est très rarement utilisé de nos jours, ce qui n’empêche nullement la bonne santé de *redondant*.

Tous ces exemples montrent qu’il existe en français d’aujourd’hui des adjectifs issus de participes, mais qui se sont détaché sémantiquement au point que parfois, la mort du verbe n’ait pas entraîné celle de l’adjectif.

On pourra donc supposer qu’il pourrait exister une certaine possibilité de considérer un suffixe *-ant* pour un nouvel adjectif, sans pour autant supposer d’emblée un verbe duquel il serait une copie du participe présent.

Est-ce déjà arrivé? En cherchant beaucoup, j’ai finalement déniché l’adjectif **mirobolant**, qui n’est pas tiré du verbe *miroboler*, lequel n’existe pas. Je crois malgré tout que l’on comprendrait facilement ceci :

> Les clowns firent s’esclaffer les enfants, puis arriva le numéro des trapézistes pendant lequel tous retinrent leur souffle, et l’écuyère acheva de **miroboler** la foule avec ses gracieuses mais combien périlleuses acrobaties.

---

**Un néologisme savant?**

Lorsque vint le temps de former un adjectif pour indiquer qu’une chose provoque le malaise, il est possible que l’on ait étudié différentes avenues. Des mots comme *malaisif* ou *malaisogène* ne doivent pas avoir retenu longtemps l’attention. Serait-il possible, par contre, qu’une personne éduquée, disposant des ressources linguistiques appropriées, ait pensé à quelque chose comme *malaisant*, et que la découverte de l’ancien verbe ait servi de justification ultime à la proposition? L’hypothèse me paraît du moins assez simple pour valoir qu’on s’y penche un peu.

Sinon, il pourrait simplement s’agir d’une création spontanée, que le seul hasard a fait pseudomorphe d’un participe présent qui se trouve avoir existé dans un lointain passé, et qui eût été parfaitement approprié pour ce nouvel usage, n’eût été qu’on ignorait son existence. Des adjectifs en *-ant* existent qui ne sont pas spontanément associés à un verbe, et ils auraient pu servir de modèle.

Comment: Merci ! C'est une belle ballade au lexique ! C'est une hypothèse intéressante à l'avant dernier para., comme une réfection soignée du verbe dans cet adjectif. Le registre me surprend, j'ai l'impression que parce que je perçois malaisé comme vieux, que ça déteint sur ma perception de malaisant et donc quand je lis ça dans la presse française je sourcille et ça ma fait l'impression d'un intense mélange des genres. _Mirobolant_ c'est une trouvaille intéressante. Pour _fendant_ je n'ai jamais réfléchi à ça mais j'ai trouvé, _fendre la face à_ pour révolter, insulter au Glossaire...

Comment: Merci d'avoir pris le temps de réfléchir là-dessus. Au final je pense qu'il y a plusieurs usages distincts qui concourent, dont le plus savant que vous avez identifié. Quand je vais avoir l'occasion je vais poser la question à des membres de ma famille dans le Bas-du-Fleuve pour voir si ils mettraient ça dans la même catégorie que _se canter_ et _greyer_.

Comment: Ce fut comme toujours un plaisir de réfléchir à l'une de vos questions. Je n'ai pas toujours la capacité de couvrir l'ensemble de vos interrogations, mais le petit bout de voyage que je fais finit toujours par m'apporter des surprises et des trouvailles intéressantes. C'est du travail de non-spécialiste, mais n'agit-on pas quotidiennement en non-spécialistes autour d'une table en bonne compagnie, pour le simple plaisir d'explorer des idées et de partager des réflexions?

Answer (score 3):

*Malaisant* vient directement de l'anglais "awkward" qui désigne une situation ou une personne gênante. Le mot est très populaire, en particulier chez les jeunes. Les québécois sont plus exposés et familier à la langue anglaise et ça arrivent qu'ils "importent" un mot ou un concept en le traduisant parfois.

Le mot est ensuite doucement arrivé en France, par le biais de l'internet j'imagine.

Personnellement j'ai connu le mot "*malaisant*" il y a quelques années sur la chaîne youtube d'un québécois et le sens correspond exactement à "awkward". Assez récemment le concept de "malaise" est devenu très répandu en France, surtout cette année et celle d'avant.

Comment: Merci d'avoir répondu. Votre propos me surprend vraiment considérant la chronologie présentée (1995 Fr, 2005 Qc dans la presse écrite)... Il y a peut-être plusieurs emplois de l'adjectif qui diffèrent. Peut-être que le sens de l'adjectif répond à un besoin contemporain ? Intéressant.

Comment: @Voléedechênesetrosiers Oui, ça arrive qu'un mot peu utilisé ou avec un sens bien précis soit "repris" avec un sens parfois légèrement différent pour exprimer un concept qui existe dans une autre langue.

Comment: Oui, malheureusement, il y une sorte de hystérie au Québec en ce qui concerne les mots "anglais" et puis on se trouve devant des phénomènes pareils. Pour moi, ce sont certaines formes structurales "anglaises" que je trouve "malaisantes" dans le français du Québec. Cela ne semble pas déranger les gens. Ils sont toujours au niveau des mots individuels, pas au niveau de la structure. Par contre, le mot malaise est utilisée en France depuis "toujours", dans des expressions comme "J'ai eu un malaise". Aussi, l'adjectif: malaisé.

Comment: @Lambie "Malaise" dans le sens de "Awkward" est assez récent. (Par exemple MalaiseTV)